# java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: EnableCassandraRepositories

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra

I am using spring boot with cassandra but enableCassandraRepositories annotation is throwing some exception , pls suggest

```
package com.tarun.application;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.config.EnableCassandraRepositories;

@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = "com.tarun.application.dao")

public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
} 
}
```

java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.config.EnableCassandraRepositories.repositoryBaseClass()
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotations(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(AnnotationUtils.java:360)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(AnnotationUtils.java:338)
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.isComponent(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:271)
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:158)
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:135)
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.load(SpringApplication.java:615)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.tarun.application.Application.main(Application.java:14)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.config.EnableCassandraRepositories.repositoryBaseClass()
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotations(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(AnnotationUtils.java:360)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(AnnotationUtils.java:338)
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.isComponent(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:271)
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:158)
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:135)
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.load(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.load(SpringApplication.java:615)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.tarun.application.Application.main(Application.java:14)

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem once when the class specified in default was not on the classpath. Check if you included [spring-data-commons](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/config/DefaultRepositoryBaseClass.java).